# FullCalendar ServerCode for JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, fullcalendar

I'm using VisualBasic for my ASPX Programming and want to do a JSON-feed for the fullcalendar.
I have this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource','ajax.vb/Test');
```

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Data.OleDb

<ScriptService()> _
Partial Public Class ajax

    <WebMethod()> _
   Public Shared Function Test(ByVal start As String, ByVal ende As String) As String
        Dim EventSource As String = ""
        Return EventSource
    End Function
End Class
```

I get back this:

> "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden -
>   =1343731700843">http://localhost:58749/ajax.vb/Test?start=1341093600&ende=1344722400&=1343731700843" 
>    The Pagetype will not be processed. 
>  Description: The requested page
>   type is not processed because it is expressly forbidden.

Do I have to use PHP (I don't really want to) or did I do sth. wrong on the serverside?
I tried the code with an vb-Class as above, an .aspx Page and with an WebService (.asmx).

What do I have to do, to sucessfully call the serverside code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use a web service and call it using http:// yourwebsite/ yourService.asmx

I am trying to utilise this as we speak and cannot find any specific documentation about connecting the calendar to a .net service that collects data from SQL.

If anyone has any information on this I would much appreciate it.

Cheers
Gwasshoppa

Comment: This may help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11662506/fullcalendar-wont-display-db-events